# Elastic search - More Like this query returning empty result

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, morelikethis

I'm using Elastic search to create some sort of tag engine. I'm inserting a document and I can't retrieve it. My steps to reproduce the issue:

1) Create index:

```
PUT index
{
"mappings": {
    "taggeable" : {
        "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
        "properties" : {
            "id" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "no"
            },
            "tags" : {
                  "type" : "text"
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Insert document:

```
POST index/taggeable
{
"id" : "1",
"tags" : "tag1 tag2"
}
```

3) Query using More like This:

```
GET index/_search
{
"query": {
    "more_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["tags"],
        "like" : ["tag1"],
        "min_term_freq" : 1
    }
}
}
```

But I'm receiving:

```
{
"_shards": {
    "failed": 0, 
    "skipped": 0, 
    "successful": 5, 
    "total": 5
}, 
"hits": {
    "hits": [], 
    "max_score": null, 
    "total": 0
}, 
"timed_out": false, 
"took": 1
}
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? I should retrieve the document I inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up the parameter

> min_term_freq
>
> The minimum term frequency below which the terms will be ignored from
>   the input document. Defaults to 2.

which is good, since otherwise it will be defaulted to 2. There is also a parameter

> min_doc_freq
>
> The minimum document frequency below which the terms will be ignored
>   from the input document. Defaults to 5.

In your case, if you have just 1 document, this will be ignored, so you either need to add more docs, or specify parameter `min_doc_freq` to 1